# Recommended desktop sharing setup on same network segment

Tags: remote-desktop, sharing

I have a few headless ubuntu machines networked to a single switch running on the same network segment.

I have a main machine running ubuntu with a monitor and i want to access to other machines.

I use GNU screen for terminal session management and would like to do something similar here with the UI. I want to run applications on the other machines and display them on my main machine.

I have heard of the following options, but not sure which way to go:

- VNC
- XDCMP
- FreeNX
- others?

Which solution will suit my needs where I can desktop share headless machines and disconnect sessions for later connection?

Answer (score 1):

I would go 100% sure for a NX connection. I use NoMachine a lot and works great.

www.nomachine.com

Just download the three .deb for ubuntu. Install and you're ready to go. Easy and fast.